# Understand structured binding in C++17 by analogy

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I'm trying to understand structured binding introduced in C++17. The explanation on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) is not obvious to me, but it looks like

```
cv-auto ref-operator [x, y, z] = ...
```

is roughly equivalent to (not to consider array case)

```
cv-auto ref-operator unique_name = ...
#define x unique_name.member_a
#define y unique_name.member_b
#define z unique_name.member_c
```

The key point here is that `x y z` are not independently defined variables, but just aliases of the return value members. And `cv-auto ref-operator` applies to the return value, not the aliases (the syntax may be misleading here). For instance, see the cppreference example

```
float x{};
char  y{};
int   z{};

std::tuple<float&,char&&,int> tpl(x,std::move(y),z);
const auto& [a,b,c] = tpl;
// a names a structured binding of type float& that refers to x
// b names a structured binding of type char&& that refers to y
// c names a structured binding of type const int that refers to the 3rd element of tpl
```

If `a b c` are independently defined variables, with `const auto&` applying to them, `c` cannot be of type `const int`.

From a practical point of view, what are the key points this analogy failed to catch?

Comment: Iterating over a list of tuples is easier.

Comment: Constness and references come to mind as something your macros don't cover.

Comment: @DeiDei those occur in the (omitted) definition of `unique_name`

Comment: This is pretty close, to my understanding

Comment: @rubenvb to reply to your comment - a copy constructor is invoked for initializing the hidden variable; and then the binding's names name members of that variable. For your `bla` it has a defaulted copy-constructor which invokes memberwise copy. In the more general case there could be a user-defined copy constructor for the struct type

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It might be insightful to consider this from another perspective.

In C++ we already had variables, objects with a name `int a = 5` and objects that aren't variables and do not have a name: `*new int`. Structured bindings are a way to have names for all parts of a variable, while the whole variable has no explicit name. So it's the combination `[x,y,z]`  that **together** names an variable with three members.

Importantly, they together name an object, so the compiler actually has to layout the object. Independent variables can be placed independently on the stack. but with structured bindings the compiler cannot do so (except for the normal `as-if` rule)

So when we consider the combination `[x y z]` as the name of the variable, it's clear that `auto const& [x y z]` makes the combination a `const&` variable.

We then have to consider what exactly the individual names `x`, `y` and `z` mean. Your question summarizes them as

```
cv-auto ref-operator unique_name = ...
#define x unique_name.member_a
#define y unique_name.member_b
#define z unique_name.member_c
```

That's a bit tricky. Where does `member_a` come from? It appears that `unique_name` has a `member_a`. You already excluded the array case, which has `[0]`. Tuples have `get<0>(tpl)`. There might very well be a `member_a` behind the `get<0>`, but the *name* `member_a`  could be private. `member_a` could also be less const-qualified than `get<0>`.

But yes, for the most simple case, a simple `struct` without bitfields, there will indeed be a corresponding `member_a`.