# What are the rules for unpacking array elements to multiple variables in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I've seen code where something like this is done:

```
auto [a, b, c] = some_array_ptr;
```

What are the rules and proper terminology for this type of assignment?

Comment: It's called a structured binding: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I'm sure this question is a dupe, I mean someone _must_ have asked this before already. But I couldn't quickly find one.

Comment: Structured binding can work with an array, not a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Translating @BessieTheCow's comment into an answer) in C++, this is called "structured binding". Read about it at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), and you may also be interested in this question here on StackOverflow:

[Understand structured binding in C++17 by analogy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49795131/1593077)

Note that not everything you might interpret as "multiple values" can actually be used in structured binding (e.g. - a pointer may point to many values but it won't work, as @Peter points out.)